# Ускорение анимации вращения элементов при скролле

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, css-animation

http://proudly.ru/febotelecom/#bl-services
Есть блок с геометрическими фигурами, они вращаются. Задача сделать ускорение вращения при скроллинге вверх или вниз. В целом, в примере это уже работает, но ощущается "тяжесть" анимации + глюки на apple устройствах.

1. Сейчас вращение реализовано через setInterval и модификацию свойства transform rotate, соответственно при скролле это значение также меняется.

```
    jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
        $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
                     'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     'zoom' : 1});
        return $(this);
    };
    
    var rotation = 0;
    var rotationLock = false;
    var rotationTid;
    setInterval(function() {
        if (!rotationLock || !__isMobile) {
            rotation += 0.5;
            $('#figure1').rotate(rotation);
            $('#figure2').rotate(rotation);
            $('#figure3').rotate(rotation);
        }
    }, 50);
    scrollCallbacks.push(function() {
        rotation += 1;
        $('#figure1').rotate(rotation);
        $('#figure2').rotate(rotation);
        $('#figure3').rotate(rotation);
        rotationLock = true;
        clearTimeout(rotationTid);
        rotationTid = setTimeout(function() {
            rotationLock = false;
        }, 100);
    });
```

2. Также была попытка реализовать это через css анимацию, а затем при скролле менять animation-duration, но эта попытка вышла более глючной.

```
    animation-name: rotation180;
    animation-duration: $speed;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    
    @keyframes rotation180 { to { transform: rotate(180deg); }}
```

Подскажите, есть ли у кого-то реальный опыт в таких интерактивных анимациях? Очень хочется всё оптимизировать до ощущения невероятности)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `requestAnimationFrame`, там fps адаптируется под устройство.

И не прибавлять константу, а опираться на текущее время (от какого-то события): rot = f(t)

Comment: Сергей, спасибо.

С requestAnimationFrame понял, спасибо)

По поводу константы, вы могли бы чуть подробнее дать пояснение?

Comment: requestAnimationFrame будет вызываться адаптивно, а не по жескому графику.
Соответственно вещи типа `+= 0.5` будут работать по-разному: то, что происходит с колесом будет зависить от того, как часто его рисуют. Может оно и так покатит. Но, чтоб было более натурально, можно взять формулу с физики "равноускоренное вращение", зависимость угла поворота от времени, как-то так: `dt=(t-t0); rot=rot0+a_half*dt*dt` -- пришел кадр, смотрим сколько время, рисуем по формуле; `t0,rot0` -- событие начала вращения.

Comment: Сергей, физика – это однозначно круто!)
Если я правильно помню курс физики, что равноускоренное — означает, что существует постоянное ускорение движения, в нашем случае вращения. Если я тут прав - ок. Далее сама формула: https://gyazo.com/b8d3c5f9ede6f25926cdff8ddb51a66b
Верно ли я ее идентифицировал?)
Если да:
В вашем примере получается, что a_half — это ускорение деленное на 2?
t0 - это какой-то таймстэмп, который мы запомнили при инициализации скрипта и начале движения?
rot0 - в нашем случае 0 (так как начинаем вращение с самого начала, далее присваивая элементу transform)?

Comment: да), но rot0 может быть не 0, если это не первое движение: вращение уже было, или есть, затем происходит событие, которое можно считать локальным "0", например начинают скролить в другую сторону.

Comment: успел спрограммировать равноускоренное вращение, после чего осознал, что это не совсем то, что нужно)
Задача ведь изначально в следующем: фигуры вращаются без ускорения в одном и том же направлении, только в случае скролла (причем не важно в какую сторону) они в каждый такой момент скролла должны приобретать небольшое ускорение в ту же сторону вращения. Как бы это правильнее реализовать? :|

Comment: можно сделать текущий стейт-объект анимации с функцией `getPos` (или просто функцию); по наступленю ключевого евента берем текущую позицию и передаем новому стейту как "0"; каждый фрейм просто берем позицию и вертим; соответственно есть классы: равномерный, равноускоренный и т. п.

Comment: Сергей, я подумал ещё и понял, что в общем-то именно равноускоренное движение здесь и не нужно: нужно просто равномерное вращение на скорости 1, а при скролле тоже самое вращение но на скорости 2 (повышенной). Это проиллюстрировано здесь: http://proudly.ru/febotelecom2/ (старый вариант, глючащий, так как без requestAnimationFrame). 
Теперь к текущей сборке, я всё сделал, залил на http://proudly.ru/febotelecom/.

Comment: Но проблема текущей заключается в том, что сам механизм requestAnimationFrame, насколько я понимаю, заключается в том, чтобы не давать перерисовывать визуал когда вздумается, а только тогда, когда это удобно девайсу. В результате имеем, что при скролле анимация, наоборот, вместо ускорения замедляется и как бы залипает на месте, так как (ну мне кажется) браузеру становится сложнее перерисовывать контент. Как же быть здесь? ://

Comment: Сергей, важное замечание к комментам выше — речь идет именно о мобильных браузерах, в десктопных все ок сейчас.

Comment: до мобильных не дошел; у меня и на десктопе файрфоксу грустно; возможно там на onscroll что-то тяжелое делается; посмотрите; и соответственно, чтоб адаптироваться браузер снижает фпс; проц не резиновый

Comment: Сергей, на главной высчитывается sticky header, текущий блок для верстикального якорного меню слева и изменение svg-волн. Я даже не знаю, что можно еще оптимизировать. С другой стороны вроде не суперсложная задача от проца здесь требуется.. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: попробуйте отключать по очереди навороты (для проверки, что тормозит); начните с svg